# azure connection issue using sql

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL DB and asp.net web application running on azure app service . I registered application in Azure AD. I am using Active directory integrated security to connect to SQL. And, I am using ADO.net entity framework.

SQL connection string is

All the app service outbound ips are added in SQl server firewall settings.

When I run the application locally (localhost), the app able to connect to SQL with no errors.

I  tried building connection string using SqlConnectionStringBuilder. I am facing the same issue.

SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

```
            builder["Data Source"] = "dbname.windows.net";

            builder["Initial Catalog"] = "dbname";

            builder["Connect Timeout"] = 15;

            builder.Authentication = SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;
```

I also tried adding connection strings in App service -> Application settings -> connection strings with SqLClinet and Custom but still no use.

Please let me know what I missed to successfully connect to Azure SQL from AppService.

Comment: For the same scenario I'm using a connection string that looks like this, without specifying any auth: `"Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"`

Comment: did you get any error message?